# MySQL error in code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the sql code in MYSQL below and I kept running into the error : 'Every derived table must have its own alias'. I already tried to name every table, but the error was still there.

```
select max(a1) - min(a1) from
  ( 
    (
      select avg(av1) as a1 
      from 
        (
          select avg(stars) as av1 
          from (rating r join movie m on r.mid=m.mid) as new1 
          where m.year < 1980
          group by r.mid) as new2 
        ) as new3 
      union
        (
          select avg(av2) as a1 
          from
            (
              select avg(stars) as av2 
              from (rating r join movie m on r.mid = m.mid
            ) as new4 
          where m.year>1980
          group by r.mid
        ) as new5
    ) as new6 
  );
```

Forgive me if this is a very stupid question to any one in here. But I have been stuck on this problem for hours already. Please point out what I did wrong . Thanks

Comment: perhaps you forget the alias on the outermost subquery `select max(a1) - min(a1) from ( .... ) xxx`

Comment: I've reformatted your SQL so that it's readable, and so you can match the start and end of each nested sub-select. See if you can figure out which one doesn't have an alias by simply checking the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query formatted so I can read it:

```
select max(a1) - min(a1)
from ((select avg(av1) as a1
       from (select avg(stars) as av1
             from (rating r join
                   movie m
                   on r.mid=m.mid
                  ) as new1
             where m.year < 1980
             group by r.mid
            ) as new2
       ) as new3 
    union
     (select avg(av2) as a1
      from (select avg(stars) as av2
            from (rating r join
                  movie m on r.mid = m.mid
                 ) as new4
            where m.year>1980
            group by r.mid
           ) as new5
     ) as new6
    )
```

You need an alias at the very end.

By the way, I don't think the `new3` is correct either.  The subqueries in  `union`/`union all` don't take aliases.